# I don't know why I can't pop up the container with correct info. check the code please, thank you in advance

Tags: javascript, php, html, promise

I have an index.php file that contains a table. here is screenshot  [image]

I want when I click  on the name here how is the name cell in my code is

```
 <td style="display:none;">$id</td>
<td ><a ondblclick="displyPopUp('playerInfo_popup', this);"><span></span> $name </a></td>
```

it shows a popup box with more info about the name being clicked where I need to get the id of the person in order to retrieve more about him from the database.
The pop up code is :

```
echo <<<HTM
<div class="popup-container" id="playerInfo_popup">
    
    <div class="popup-content ">
HTM;

$person_id =  $_GET['id'];

echo <<<HTM
    person id is : $person_id 
       
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
HTM;
```

and the js code is

```
async function displyPopUp(popId, element){
  let id = element.parentElement.parentElement.children[0].textContent;
  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const current_href = window.location.href;
  const state = {id:12}
  const title = 'test'
  const url = current_href + '?id=' + id + '&playerInfo_popup=1';

  await new Promise(resolve => {
    history.pushState(state, title, url);
    resolve();


  });
  
  foo(popId, current_href);
}




function foo(popId, current_href) {
  const popupContainer = document.getElementById('playerInfo_popup');
    const closeButton = document.querySelector('.fa-circle-xmark')
      popupContainer.classList.add('show');
      closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        popupContainer.classList.remove('show');
        window.location.href = current_href;
      });
      popupContainer.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
        popupContainer.classList.remove('show');
      });
}
```

the popup is being displayed and the popup is showing but the id is not shown here is screen shot after I click any name [image]

the url is being updated  but $_GET['id'] is still null
please help me to fix this code

Comment: it will be a number even if set it to discrete number the problem will not be changed I tried console.log(id) = 1 and the url is in the search bar `http://localhost/?id=1&playerInfo_popup=1`